# How to get array from controller on javascript blade in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project and am trying to pass an array from a controller to javascript. The following code is from my controller.

```
 $dicomfilearray = $dicom->pluck('filename')->toArray();
 return view('xray.view')->withDicomfilearray($dicomfilearray);
```

And below is the Javascript in that's in the blade file I'm trying to pass it to.

```
var dicomarray = '{{ json_encode($dicomfilearray) }}';
console.log(dicomarray);
```

And the following is a log result from the Javascript.

```
[&quot;storage/uploads/storeid1/27/10/dicom/c4p4Oco3rU.dcm&quot;,&quot;storage/uploads/storeid1/27/10/dicom/RNil0NPPzQ.dcm&quot;]
```

I would like to get a list from this array. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make ajax call in frotend, and backend do like this

```
$dicomfilearray = json_encode($dicom->pluck('filename'))->toArray()); 
return view('xray.view')->withDicomfilearray($dicomfilearray);
```

Comment: Dear Bimal Prasad Pandey, I would like to return to view instead. Appreciated to advice.

Comment: $dicomfilearray = json_encode($dicom->pluck('filename'))->toArray());
return view('xray.view')->withDicomfilearray($dicomfilearray);

Comment: I have to work on another new view that why I'm not use ajax. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

when you working in javascript and need data in javascript then why you need `view` part. Actually, I just read your comment.
*If in Ajax*

so I suggest send array with `json_encode` and populate that data into view with javascript.
simply right below in controller

`response()->json(['status'=>200,'data'=>$dicomfilearray])`

**Update**
So ,you not sending ajax request so, simply. do like below.

controller:-

```
$data = json_encode($dicomfilearray);
    return view('your-view',compact('data'));
```

javascript

```
var dicomarray = '{{ $data }}';
```

Comment: Dear Karan Sadana, No not ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and this even works if you want to pass the variable to external javascript file. All you have to do is to call the init function with passed parameters.

```
 <script>      
    $(function () {
         init({{ json_encode($dicomfilearray) }} });
         function init(dicomfilearray){
        //use your variable here  
      }
</script>
```